# Does the sentence "Just as many would agree, I, too, believe that..." sound okay?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

This is the first sentence of the conclusion of my essay:

> Just as many would agree, I, too, believe that...

I don't want to use "also" just to avoid repetition in the subsequent sentence. Does it sound good to you in the formal writing? I am unsure of that because there are three consecutive commas. Or, are there any better alternatives?

Comment: 'I am one of the many who believe ....'

Comment: I guess you don't need to add a comma between *I,too*... You can say - *"I too, just as many would agree, believe that...."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Too" does not require to be enclosed with commas.

The sentence is okay without those commas, as in:

> "Just as many would agree, I too believe that..."

Hope this clears.